# Spring mvc CommonsMultipartResolver

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am trying to use spring mvc to build web app.
Before I was using

```
<bean id="jspViewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"/>
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"/>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
</bean>
```

But now, because i need to upload files also, i have to change to

```
<bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
    <property name="maxUploadSize" value="1000000"/>
</bean>
```

This multipartResolver doesn't have attributes like prefix. 
If I need to use multipartResolver, where can I set the prefix and suffix?

Please give me suggestions, thank you!!!

Comment: In Spring MVC you don't have to use the `ServletRequest` to look for parameters. This is very basic Spring MVC stuff and any decent tutorial should give you at least one way to do it.

Comment: Thank you, but i am not really reading some object in. I just need those parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The properties "prefix" and "suffix" are properties specific for the InternalResourceViewResolver.  There are no properties on the CommonsMultipartResolver for this.

You need those properties to advise the InternalResourceViewResolver to tell it where to find jsp files (for example, if you return a string of "foo", it will resolve with the "{prefix}foo{suffix}", which is "/WEB-INF/jsp/foo.jsp").

There is no need to define a prefix and suffix for the CommonsMultipartResolver.  Per the comments in source code, the properties that CommonsMultipartResolver can use are "maxUploadSize", "maxInMemorySize", and "defaultEncoding".

Comment: Thank you. But if I just use commons multipartResolver, how should my code know where to load the jsp page?

Comment: As I said, it's a separate thing altogether.  Perhaps you are not adding both the jspViewResolver and multipartResolver beans in your config?  You don't have to 'change' the bean node in your xml, you add an additional bean node.